# Windows 8.1 - I'm admin but cannot change time

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8.1

Windows 8.1 managed to get on my nerves today.
I tried all methods found by searching google and didn't manage to change the date and time.

I'm logged as ADMIN (local user) , the single account on the system. Even though I'm adimin I can't change the time. It either gives me and error specifying I need to be admin to do it or just ignores my change and does nothing (for ex when I click the "PC Settings" menu on the right sidebar....).

Is there a way to change the time on Windows 8.1 or am I asking to much ?

Comment: @kawa, Did you just click on the time in the taskbar and click `Change date and time settings...`? Can you confirm your account actually has administrative privileges, through `Control Panel` => `User Accounts` => `Change your account type`?

Comment: Post a screenshot of `Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\User Accounts`